# .NET Linq Search List of String Contains

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I have a List(Of String) containing Hardware PNP IDs e.g.

```
ListOfPNPIds = List(Of String)
    
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B&SUBSYS_22A817AA&REV_00
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B&SUBSYS_22A817AA
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B&CC_030000
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B&CC_0300
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B
```

I am then reading driver inf files into a second List(Of String) but the lines containing the hardware ID contain other text preventing me from doing a simple match e.g.

```
ListOfDriverInf = List(Of String)

%iCFLDTGT1%           = iCFL_w10_DS, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E90
%iCFLDTGT2%           = iCFL_w10_DS, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E92
%iCFLDTWSGT2%         = iCFL_w10_DS, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E96
%iCFLHALOGT2%         = iCFL_w10_DS, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B
```

How can I search ListOfDriverInf to find if any item contains one (or more) of the items in ListOfPNPIds

I have attempted a few different Linq queries but can't seem to get Linq to search the substring items of ListOfDriverInf for items contained in ListOfPNPIds.

This will return the result I'm after but it doesn't search the ListOfPNPIds list

```
Dim result = ListOfDriverInf.Any(Function(x) x.Contains("PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B"))
```

For example I tried:

```
ListOfPNPIds.Any(Function(p) ListOfDriverInf.Find(Function(s) s.Contains(p)))
```

What I am after is a Linq query that will return a value when there's a match for:

```
ListOfPNPIds
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B
```

**matches**

```
ListOfDriverInf
%iCFLHALOGT2%         = iCFL_w10_DS, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the appropriate .net language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `EndsWith` for the comparison.

```
Dim listOfPNPIds = New List(Of String)() From {
    "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B&SUBSYS_22A817AA&REV_00",
    "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B&SUBSYS_22A817AA",
    "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B&CC_030000",
    "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B&CC_0300",
    "PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B"
}
Dim listOfDriverInf = New List(Of String)() From {
    "%iCFLDTGT1%           = iCFL_w10_DS, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E90",
    "%iCFLDTGT2%           = iCFL_w10_DS, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E92",
    "%iCFLDTWSGT2%         = iCFL_w10_DS, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E96",
    "%iCFLHALOGT2%         = iCFL_w10_DS, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_3E9B"
}
Dim result = listOfDriverInf.Where(
    Function(x) listOfPNPIds.Any(
        Function(y) x.EndsWith(y)))
```

Comment: When I run your code I get result = nothing.

Comment: @Ben If you run the exact code, you should get the one match (the last DriverInf).

Comment: If the above does not do it for some reason, perhaps there is white space or something else, you can change `x.endsWith(y)` to `x.contains(y)`

Comment: I have found the reason I'm getting nothing! The driver inf I'm trying to install contains this line: "%TEE_DeviceDesc%=TEE_DDI_W8, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_5A9A    ;BXT-P" which means the x doesn't end with y